# Return the entire line on information from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df that looks like :

```
            Date  Last Price
0     29/11/2016       56.87
1     28/11/2016       57.32
2     27/11/2016       55.56
3     22/11/2016       58.66
4     21/11/2016       57.98
5     20/11/2016      790.22
```

I am identifying outliers in the time-series using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std

    def outliers(df):   

        data_mean, data_std = mean(df['Last Price']), std(df['Last Price'])

        print('data_mean ',data_mean)
        print('data_std ',data_std)
        cut_off = data_std * 3
        lower, upper = data_mean - cut_off, data_mean + cut_off

        outliers = [x for x in df['Last Price'] if x < lower or x > upper]
```

This returns the outlier output in a list format:

```
[790.22]

Identified outliers: 1
```

How can I return the entire line from the `df` into a `list` or `dataframe`?  So my desired output would be:

```
20/11/2016      790.22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.iloc[idx].to_list()` where `idx` corresponds to your row number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop for filtering your dataframe, you can do this instead:

```
is_outlier1 = df['Last Price'] < lower 
is_outlier2 = df['Last Price'] > upper

outliers = df[is_outlier1][is_outlier2]
```

This will return outliers in form of a dataframe.